# A question about choosing LORs in a particular case

Tags: etiquette, recommendation-letter

I know that the topic of letters of recommendation is already a topic in this community and I have read many posts about it, but it seems to be a topic that never ends up raising new questions. Here I have one that has come up.

It is application season and, as is often the case for upperclassmen majoring in a Degree, I am sending out a lot of applications for different programs.

I would like to know which of the following hypothetical options are best for sending letters of recommendation.

1. A professor who knows me well and I know that his letter will be
   very strong, positive and personalized, but whose digital presence
   is low and I don't know what impact it can have.
2. A professor with a high presence and a quite good reputation, but who
   knows me less so I fear that his letter is more generic.
3. A professor with a very solid career and digital and research
   presence, who has already shown interest in supporting me, but from
   whom I would have to ask for the letter in a short time (say, a
   week).

Most programs allow you to send two letters, but you may be able to send more, in which case the only problem would be choosing the primary reference and whether it is worth bothering the professor in case three with whom I want to have a very good academic relationship.

Thank you very much in advance for your answers.

Comment: I don't know very many professors who care about their 'digital presence' much at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My advice in all such situations is to ignore, more or less, the "prestige" of the letter writer in favor of the knowledge of the person about you and your work. The letter writer needs to honestly and confidently predict your success. A generic letter from a superstar isn't really impressive in that regard. Admissions committees are unlikely to say "wow" because some superstar suggests you'll probably do fine.

Get letters from people with whom you've worked and impressed. The exception would be from people who don't hold doctorates and who can't really speak to the likelihood of your success.

The important thing is what they say, not who they are.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Buffy! Just a question, what do you understand as people who can't really speak to the likelihood of my future success? You mean, like people with whom you barely had contact? Like people who neither lectured you nor worked with you?

Comment: Even getting good marks in a single course isn't likely to be ideal. Several courses, seminars, projects, research... all are better. Even frequent office visits where you discuss things in the field. Sort of automatic at US liberal arts colleges. Harder at R1 universities.

Answer (score 1):

The prestige of faculty is their own, not yours (especially in this situation). It won't help you as much as you think (or hardly at all unless you apply to a low-grade program with naive admissions people). Also, as I have observed over the years, undergraduate students have a VERY FLAWED perception of who is actually well regarded in the broader community anyway. It's often not those who are "highly visible" within the University. The real notable people are off giving invited lectures all over the world and don't bother with low level self-promotion.

So ignore that, pick someone who can write a strong letter about YOU. Which means they must have had meaningful interactions with you.